# How to re-load a web page when window is resized and only if it contains a particular HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a jQuery statement to my website so that, if a user re-sizes the browser window, the web page is re-loaded but ONLY if that page also contains an HTML (DIV) element with a class of ".bx-slider".

I think I need to wrap an IF statement around the following but I would really appreciate some help on how to do this:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function(){ 
     window.location.href = window.location.href; 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check the element exists then do you what you want.

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
     if( $('.bx-slider').length ) {
          location.reload();
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I just put the IF statement around the resize function and it's working fine.